# perlbrew custom folder for libs

Tags: perl, perlbrew

When I use

```
perlbrew lib create testlibs
```

to have a folder to store test libraries from CPAN, it creates a folder under the following path:

```
$HOME/.perlbrew/libs/perl-5.32.0@testlibs/lib/perl5
```

How can I tell perlbrew to store the libs folder ( **perl-5.32.0@testlibs** ) under a different folder such as /opt/perl5/libs, etc.?

I have very little disk space for home mountpoint on my server, so I need libs folders to be created on a different mountpoint. I already have PERLBREW_ROOT set to a different mountpoint, but that only makes perlbrew install new perl installation folders under it. It doesn't do it for the libs folders, which was surprising.

I already read the documentation and googled the hell out of this, but I can't find some env variable I can use to tell perlbrew where to install libs folders.

I know I can manipulate locallib env variables and even use lib on my scripts to point to some other folder, but it would be nice to have this all included within perlbrew.

Comment: It appears to be relative to `PERLBREW_HOME`

Comment: I read the doc for that env variable, but I totally missed the point to related to this. Thank you very much. This worked. I hope the perlbrew admin adds this to "libs" section in the documentation.